# All-day event in Lotus Notes using iCalendar

Tags: calendar, lotus-notes, icalendar

I am trying to create an .ics file that can be used to import all-day events.

I'm using the following code in the .ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john.doe@example.com
DTSTART;TSID="GMT":20110719T040000
DTEND;TSID="GMT":20110719T200000
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SUMMARY:Holiday
X-LOTUS-UPDATE-SEQ:1
X-LOTUS-NOTESVERSION:2
X-LOTUS-APPTTYPE:2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I exported a test all-day event, so I could check the formatting, but it still does not display in the top panel as an all-day event.

Does anyone know how to get an event to appear as an all-day event in Lotus Notes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct solution was to remove the time from the DTSTART and DTEND e.g.

```
DTSTART;TSID="GMT":20110719T040000  ==> DTSTART;TSID="GMT":20110719
```

Hope this helps some people.

Answer (score 2):

This is a working example:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//innerjoin.org/NONSGML Innerjoin iCal Test Case Gen 20050301//EN

BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20050301-96412-innerjoin-org
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20050301
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20050302
DTSTAMP:20050301
URL:
 http://www.innerjoin.org/iCalendar/test-cases/20050301-20050302.txt
SUMMARY:
 Event from 20050301 to 20050302
DESCRIPTION:
 Event starting at 20050301 and lasting until 20050302\n
 - Option:  Starting on 20050301\n
 - Option:  Ending on 20050302\n
 - Default: No timezone specified\, using local time\n
 - Default: No status given\, not necessarily confirmed\n
 - Default: No class given\, treat event details as publicly accessible\n
 - Default: Event treated as opaque
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Thanks Jasper. Did you try importing that exported event and seeing if it appears correctly? I tried your .ics and it didn't appear properly (it drew an event from 03:00 - 19:00).

Comment: Oops, I missed this line: "I exported a test all-day event, so I could check the formatting, but it still does not display in the top panel as an all-day event." I will test it now.

Comment: I updated the answer with a working example. It seems that there is no type for all day event, it can be done with the date/time